# How to allow 'http' only in the Access Rules array

Tags: php, yii

In Yii, I am finding a way how to restrict the url that accesses my controller actions to 'http' only. I am thinking about how to get the url in a Yii way so that I can place my code in the 'expression' attribute of the array.

Comment: use .htaccess, you can restrict all your URL inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a filter method in your base controller (`components/Controller.php`):

```
public function filterOnlyHttp($filterChain = null) {
    if (Yii::app()->request->isSecureConnection) {
        $this->redirect('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].Yii::app()->request->requestUri);
    }else
        $filterChain->run();
}
```

It will redirect your `https://` to `http://` requests. You can configure this filter for specific controller actions in a [`filters()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter) method in a controller:

```
public function filters() 
{
    return array(
        'httpOnly',
    );
}
```

If you generally want that redirect *all* your `https` requests, then you could also put the `if` above (without the `else` part) into the `init()` method of your base controller in `components/Controller.php`.

Answer (score -1):

Try defaultScheme/validSchemes

array('url', 'url','defaultScheme' => 'http')

array('url', 'url','validSchemes' => array('http'));

Check this for more info http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/#hh23